# t-sql maximum date on self join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In t-sql 2008, I have a table that I need to join to itself server items based upon customer number, cust_date, and attribute id.
The attrribute id values are 53, 54, and 55. There are the same attribute ids that can occur lots of times during the year so the cust_date can change.
I need to join rows in the table to itself several times where the cust_date is the same and the most current date.

Thus can you show me how to join the table to itself with selecting the maximum cust_date and the for attribute value = 53, 54, and 55?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement you may not need a join but could do something like

```
select customerNumber, 
  Max(case where attributeid = 53 then Cust_date else null end) as A53CustDate,
  Max(case where attributeid = 54 then Cust_date else null end) as A54CustDate,
  Max(case where attributeid = 55 then Cust_date else null end) as A55CustDate,
from MyTable
where Attributeid in (53,54,55)
group by
  CustomerNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
select customerNumber, 
   Case when attributeid in (53,54,55) Then max(cust_date) else NULL END as CustDate
from MyTable
group by
  CustomerNumber
```

Comment: I do need to join this table to other tables based upon customer number. Thus how would I join this table to other jobs and still have max(cust_date)

Comment: It depends on what you are joining.. You have to be specific on your question.

Comment: @user1816979 : If you think the answer give was right as you upvote, you can mark the the answer as well...

Answer (score 0):

Supposed I understood you correctly, the following should do the trick. I define a cte where I get the customer number, attribute and max date for all records of attribute types 53-55 and then join the result against your initial table:

```
WITH cte AS(
  SELECT customerNumber, attributeid , max(Cust_date) AS Cust_date
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Attributeid in (53,54,55)
    GROUP BY customerNumber, attributeid
)
SELECT a.*
  FROM MyTable AS a
  JOIN cte AS b
    ON b.customerNumber = a.customerNumber
    AND b.attributeid = a.attributeid
    AND b.Cust_date = a.Cust_date
```